# Distance between 2 coordinates 2D array

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office

I have a unique identifier (column A) with its respective set of coordinates (DD units, ex. 59, -110) for 500+ locations and would like to write a macro that creates a 2D array (500+ X 500+) and automatically populates each cell within the array with the distance between all of the other coordinates in the data set.

Sample Data set (starting in A1):

```
ID       Lat  Long    
A        59   -110    
B        58   -105    
C        62   -103
```

Hopefully I can create an array that looks like this:

```
    A  B  C    
A   0  X  Y    
B   X  0  Z    
C   Y  Z  0
```

The formula to calculate the distance between the two coordinates is:

```
=ACOS( SIN(lat1*PI()/180)*SIN(lat2*PI()/180) + COS(lat1*PI()/180)*COS(lat2*PI()/180)*COS(long2*PI()/180-long1*PI()/180) ) * 6371000
```

In addition to this, if possible I would like to add a row onto the end of the array that gives the lowest distance calculated that is not zero.

This is what I have so far:

```
Const R2D As Double = (3.1459 / 180) 
Const MagicNumber As Long = 637100  
Private Function GetDistances(Lat1 As Double, Lat2 As Double, Long1 As Double, Long2 As Double) As Double

GetDistances = Acos(Sin(Lat1) * Sin(Lat2) * R2D ^ 2 + Cos(Lat1) * Cos(Lat2) * Cos(Long2) * R2D ^ 3 - Long1 * R2D) * MagicNumber

End Function



Sub MakeMatrix()

Dim Originals As Variant
Dim Distances As Variant
Dim Results As Double
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, l As Long
Dim Rws As Long
Const Lat As Long = 1
Const Lon As Long = 2
Const MinDistance = 0.01


Rws = Cells(Rows, Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row - 1


Originals = Application.Transpose(Range(Cells(2, "B"), Cells(Rws, "C"))).Value
ReDim Distances(1 To Rws1, 1 To Rws)


For i = LBound(Originals) To UBound(Originals)
 For j = LBound(Originals) To UBound(Originals)
   Results = GetDistance(Lat1:=Originals(i, Lat), Lat2:=Originals(j, Lat),  Long1:=Originals(i, Lon), Long1:=Originals(j, Lon))


   If Results > MinDistance Then Distances(i, j) = Results

 Next j: Next i


Range("F1").Resize(Rws, Rws) = Distances

End Sub
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated

New to stack so if there's any additional information needed please ask

Thanks in advance

Comment: Since the earth isn't really spherical, you are introducing distortions. You could consider using [Vincenty's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincenty%27s_formulae) if you want or need something more accurate. In any event -- what exactly is the problem with your code? It would help if you describe what is going wrong.

Comment: What is `Rws1`? You need `Option Explicit` at the top of your module. Also your `Rws = Cells(Rows, Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row - 1` syntax is off - that should be `Rows.Count`.

Comment: Also, you have `Long1` in your `GetDistance()` equation twice - you need to carefully proofread line by line, but definitely start with `Option Explicit` to help you catch glaring errors - it will prevent your code from compiling with them.

Comment: It is difficult to exaggerate the importance of @dwirony 's point about `Optional Explicit`. Rather than leaving it to chance -- you can once and for all go to the `Options` tab in the VBA editor and enable the option "Require Variable Declaration" (or words to that effect). I have always found it odd that this isn't the default in the editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had some issue with `Acos` function not working so I did it my way, from scratch and following a formula found [here](http://ezinearticles.com/?How-to-Build-in-a-Simple-Distance-Checker-Between-Two-UK-Postcodes-Into-Your-Access-Database-in-VBA&id=2408262)

> Distance = (Sin((Me.TxtEndLat * 3.14159265358979) / 180)) *
>   (Sin((Me.TxtStartLat * _ 
>   3.14159265358979) / 180)) + (Cos((Me.TxtEndLat * 3.14159265358979) / 180)) *  _  ((Cos((Me.TxtStartLat * 3.14159265358979) / 180))) * _ 
>               (Cos((Me.TxtStartLong - Me.TxtEndLong) * (3.14159265358979 / 180)))
>
> Distance = 6371 * (Atn(-Distance / Sqr(-Distance * Distance + 1)) + 2
>   * Atn(1))

It takes data in `Sheet1` and outputs the matrix in `Sheet2`

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim sheetSource As Worksheet
    Dim sheetResults As Worksheet

    Dim intPos As Long
    Dim intMax As Long

    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim strID As String

    Dim dblDistance As Double
    Dim dblTemp As Double

    Dim Lat1 As Double 
    Dim Lat2 As Double 
    Dim Long1 As Double 
    Dim Long2 As Double 

    Const PI As Double = 3.14159265358979

    Set sheetSource = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set sheetResults = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    intPos = 1

    ' 1 Build the matrix
    For i = 2 To sheetSource.Rows.Count

        strID = Trim(sheetSource.Cells(i, 1))

        If strID = "" Then Exit For

        intPos = intPos + 1

        sheetResults.Cells(intPos, 1) = strID
        sheetResults.Cells(1, intPos) = strID

    Next i

    intMax = intPos


    If intMax = 1 Then Exit Sub ' no data


    ' 2 : compute matrix
    For i = 2 To intMax 'looping on lines

        Lat1 = sheetSource.Cells(i, 2)
        Long1 = sheetSource.Cells(i, 3)

        For j = 2 To intMax 'looping on columns

            Lat2 = sheetSource.Cells(j, 2)
            Long2 = sheetSource.Cells(j, 3)

            ' Some hard trigonometry over here
            dblTemp = (Sin((Lat2 * PI) / 180)) * (Sin((Lat1 * PI) / 180)) + (Cos((Lat2 * PI) / 180)) * _
                      ((Cos((Lat1 * PI) / 180))) * (Cos((Long1 - Long2) * (PI / 180)))


            If dblTemp = 1 Then ' If 1, the 2 points are the same. Avoid a division by zero
                 sheetResults.Cells(i, j) = 0
            else
                 dblDistance = 6371 * (Atn(-dblTemp / Sqr(-dblTemp * dblTemp + 1)) + 2 * Atn(1))
                 sheetResults.Cells(i, j) = dblDistance
            End If

        Next j
    Next i


End Sub
```

Results :

```
        A             B             C           
A   0             310,9566251   507,6414335
B   310,9566251   0             458,4126121
C   507,6414335   458,4126121   0
```

A quick test done [here](https://www.geodatasource.com/distance-calculator) between A and B shows that the resut is almost identical : The site gives `310.94 KM` and my function gives `310,9566251`, which is a difference of +/- 15 cm. Over 300 km, that's acceptable.

I can thus safely assume that it works.

Now you can tweak it ;)

Comment: Thank you for the solution @Thomas_G, I am having an issue with it applying because some of my coordinates are different by just a few decimal degrees so when it runs instead of giving an answer in the hundreds of meters (or tenths of a kilometer) it just returns zero which is not ideal. Do you think you could run it again but this time exchange the data in row A for (54.14502, -116.69005) and row B (54.075045, -116.766720). In short I have to work around the statement you have written in to prevent divide by zero errors. Sorry for not being specific enough earlier.

Comment: As far as `ACOS` goes, you could use `Application.WorksheetFunction.Acos` (which is likely one of the problems that OP had).

Comment: @ThomasG It isn't surprising that you did, though OP seemed to be unaware that it isn't a built-in VBA function. Perhaps the [Haversine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) formula might be the best way to go since Wikipedia says that is has better numerical stability for small distances. In any event, +1 for a solution that OP should be able to tweak.

Comment: @cwassmuth on phone omw back home. Normally you just have to declare lat1 lat2 long1 long2 as Double insteand of Long and that should work

Comment: @ThomasG I will try that and update on the result! Thanks!

Comment: @ThomasG that fixed the issue! however new problem now, when I run it on my real data the function runs for 5 rows and then on the 5th data set when the function reaches the point where the two data points are the same, instead of producing a 0 like the previous 4 times it stops and gives the 'invalid procedure call or argument' run-time error and when I debug it, it points to the dblDistance = 6371 * (Atn(-dblTemp / Sqr(-dblTemp * dblTemp + 1)) + 2 * Atn(1))...Any thoughts? Thanks for all of the help

Comment: @ThomasG if I am running the code on a 500 X 500 array do you think it could have reached a calculation limit? is there a way around this

Comment: It should handle a 500x500 without issue... whats the problem exactly?